# AngularJS template with brackets in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Why AngularJS doesn't accept brackets inside a ng-template content? I need it to create an input that's going to be an array, but I get this error:
"Error: Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression at column 15 of the expression [form.interval[]] starting at []]."

```
angular.module("main", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
}).directive("ngPortlet", function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Interval" ng-model="form.interval[]" />',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elm) {
            scope.add = function(){
                console.log(elm);
               elm.after($compile('<ng-portlet></ng-portlet>')(scope));
            }
        }
    };
});

<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="container">
        <button ng-click="add()" >Add</button>
        <ng-portlet></ng-portlet>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7kcrrapm/1/

Comment: ngmodel is a reference to the single value that the input element's value is bound to.  an array is not a single value.   What are you exepcting to do here?

Comment: I need to dinamically add hour intervals. So in the end I'll have the model interval as : [1,2,3,4,5,6] (just an example of what I would fill in)

Comment: Why don't you use a two-way binding `scope` for that array in your directive?

Comment: ok, so you want to evaluate the text box contents, extract the string, and convert each comma separated value into an array value?

Comment: No @Claies I want to add a new input for each interval, by clicking on an add button, and in the end retrieve all of them in that model as an array, just like I would do in normal html, like name="interval[]"

Comment: so you are typing one entry at a time into the textbox?

Comment: Correct, if I want another one I create another input for it by clicking on add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, what you really want is ng-repeat.

```
<span ng-repeat="hour in form.interval">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Interval" ng-model="hour" />
</span>
```

Declare the variable inside the controller or directive:

```
$scope.form.interval = [];
```

When you do `add()` to get another input, add a blank entry to the array in the controller or directive:

```
$scope.form.interval.push('');
```

Call `add()` when you create the variable if you want to start with one empty input box.

Comment: Thank you your solution works and it's much more simpler, I don't know why I didn't think of doing this way haha. Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Now that I better understand what you're trying to accomplish, here is a different approach:

```
angular.module("main", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
}).directive("ngPortlet", function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Interval" ng-model="interval" />',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elm) {
            var intervals = [];
            scope.add = function(){
                intervals.push(parseInt(scope.interval, 10));
                console.log(intervals);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Now you have access to an array (`intervals`) that contains a list of all intervals added.

ORIGINAL:

`form.interval[]` is not valid JavaScript and thus not a valid scope property. If you need the property to be an array you can simply declare it in your controller ("MyCtrl"):

`$scope.form.interval = [];`

If you don't create the scope property in the controller your self, it will be implicitly created by the `ng-model` directive. You can find more info [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). I might also suggest this great read about [Scopes in the official Angular Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: this still doesn't make sense to me; if you assign `$scope.form.interval = []` then try to use `ng-model="form.interval"`, which element of the array is that single text box supposed to represent?

Comment: @Claies you're right. It doesn't make sense to make the form input itself an array, since it's a single input. I've updated my answer which includes a separate array, where the value of the input is pushed.

Comment: Thank you I will also try this, but got it working also using ng-repeat which is more simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working, is because `[]` is invalid JavaScript syntax on a variable reference.

```
interval = [1, 2, 3]; // Ok.
interval = [];        // Also Ok.
var foo = interval[]; // This isn't valid!
```

Take those square brackets off, or if you're wanting to do a `ng-repeat` setup you might consider some of the other given answers.